# Will a version 6.x module work in v7.x?

Tags: 7

Is it possible that an older version of a module works when it has not been upgraded to 7 or is it a lost cause to try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module versions must match the core version to work. Drupal 6 modules will not work on Drupal 7.

Comment: How major was the change? Is it the kind of thing where they changed everything or that a few core functions changed and would need tweaking in a revision to modules?  Where can I read more about it?

Comment: Take a look at [Converting 6.x modules to 7.x](http://drupal.org/node/224333)

Answer (score 2):

Without updating a module to Drupal 7, the module will not work on the new Drupal version.

The first reason is that Drupal 7 looks for a line containing "core = 7.x" in the .info file of the module; if the file doesn't contain that line, or contains a different version ID, such as 6.x, the module will be reported not to be compatible with Drupal 7.

Even if you would edit that file, the module could not still work, depending from the implemented hooks.
If the module is implementing a hook that has been renamed in Drupal 7, it will not work; the same is true if the arguments of the hook have been changed. For example, `hook_nodeapi()` has been replaced from a family of hooks, whose name is generally `hook_node_$op()`, where `$op` was the parameter passed to `hook_nodeapi()`. Finally, in few cases, a hook that was already used in Drupal 6 has changed purpose in Drupal 7; an example of this is [hook_hook_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_hook_info/7) that in Drupal 7 defines which files are used from a module to implement its hooks, while [hook_hook_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_hook_info/6) was used in Drupal 6 to define the triggers to which the users could associate actions.

There are also hooks that have not been renamed, or for which the parameters didn't change, but it's rare that a module just uses those hooks.

Answer (score 0):

A large portion of the [Drupal 7 API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/7) has changed from the [Drupal 6 API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/6), so it is unlikely that a module will work as-is.  It is still possible, though, for some small modules to not use any changed functions.

Note that you can't take a D6 module and just plunk it into a D7 installation anyway.  The core version is specified in the modules's .info file.

Would I try this?  No.

If a module hasn't been ported to Drupal 7, then it is likely that it either isn't needed or it isn't being maintained anyway (which is a warning sign).